# ReaderWriterLockSlim: acquiring a read lock after an upgradeable lock doesn't throw LockRecursionException

Tags: .net, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

Concerning the `ReaderWriterLockSlim`:

Acquiring two locks subsequently within the **same** thread should actually throw a `LockRecursionException` (the recursion policy is set to `NoRecursion`).

My observation results:

- *reader* lock, then *reader* lock --> `LockRecursionException`
- *reader* lock, then *upgradeable reader* lock --> `LockRecursionException`
- *reader* lock, then *writer* lock --> `LockRecursionException`
- *upgradeable reader* lock, then *reader* lock --> **no exception**
- *upgradeable reader* lock, then *upgradeable reader* lock --> `LockRecursionException`
- *upgradeable reader* lock, then *writer* lock --> **no exception**
- *writer* lock, then *reader* lock --> `LockRecursionException`
- *writer* lock, then *upgradeable reader* lock --> `LockRecursionException`
- *writer* lock, then *writer* lock --> `LockRecursionException`

Is this behavior correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx):

> A thread in upgradeable mode can downgrade to read mode by first calling the `EnterReadLock` method and then calling the `ExitUpgradeableReadLock` method. This downgrade pattern is allowed for all lock recursion policies, even `NoRecursion`.

My understanding is that for the *writing* situation, entering a write lock is the normal way to move from upgradeable to write mode anyway, so has to be supported even under a policy of `NoRecursion` (there would seem to be little point to a non-upgradeable upgradeable lock :)

Comment: Yes, that would be my understanding as well. Those two paths are the normal upgrade and downgrade scenarios. Therefore they must be allowed regardless of the recursion policy. The confusion on my part stemmed at least in part from the fact that I never thought of it as a _downgradeable_ lock as well..

Comment: @JohnSloper No, I hadn't realised it was downgradeable either. Handy though, if a thread can determine that it no longer needs to write.